# WinSpy or Inspect analog for .NET (managed) applications

Tags: windows, gui

I am looking for software similar to [the `Inspect` program from the Windows SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which can effectively interact with managed applications on the latest x64 Windows platforms. Are there any alternatives?

EDIT:

I'm looking for the alternative, because the `Inspect` tool fails to find certain controls. For example, i wanted to automatiate choosing the ssl certificate in the programm written with managed code, based on the Firefox Gecko engine. There will appear the window, with certificate selection. Inspect and other tools will fail to find the control id's on this window, MSAA Ui Automation doesn't work.

Basicaly i just need to view the control identificators, their properties, to understand how can i retrieve them programmaticaly, (maybe using managed dll injection or something like that)

Comment: UI Automation is as modern as it gets. The problem is that embedded browsers don't expose controls to UIA. Desktop Chrome supports UIA, but you need to configure your browser's flags. Firefox doesn't support it yet. If a browser is an embedded Forefox, you're out of luck - you can't get manually drawn controls if the app does nothing to expose them.